# Removing title box from jchartfx chart using jquery

Tags: jquery, jchartfx

I am currently using jchartfx to render some charts, my problem is I cannot find any way to remove the very large title created for each graph.

```
$("#sales").chart({
        axisY : {
            min : 0,
            max : salesMax,
        },
        dataValues : items,
            titles : [ {
                        text : ""
            } ]
});
```

If I leave the string empty as in the example above, I get a default text instead. I must do this jquery-wise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up switching over from jquery to Javascript, this library is not supported enough for jquery.

Answer (score 0):

I went to the jchartfx [demo site](http://www.jchartfx.com/jChartFXGallery/), analyzed the DOM and tried this in my browser's console:

```
$('.Title').hide();
```

No longer was I able to see any title.

Comment: This indeed removes the title but not the titles structure, the frame still remains and it takes about 1/6th of height from the graph.

Comment: Does your chart look much different from the demos? Analyzing the demo charts, there doesn't seem to be a frame or structure for the title. You could, however, remove the first couple of `<path>` elements of the chart's `<svg>` in order to make the chart's frame disappear.

Comment: If I remove the frame using javascript, there is still a 1/6th empty space. Sorry I was not specific about this in my initial post.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the title box using the following in the jQuery options used to customize the chart

```
notitlebox: true,
```